# how to store values of list items in array on check box click and remove on unclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a quote page where the user can click on features which will be in the form text field and the user can also request a quote

here is what I did so far

```
        <div class="buy-features-box">
                            <div class="box-head">
                                <div class="box-head-content">
                                    <div class="package-name">
                                        <h2>Sample features for Seller/ Vendor</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-all-btn">
                                        <input class="btn-check check1 form-check-input" name="product" value="100" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()">
                                        <a href="#" class="theme-button grey-button ">SELECT ALL</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="collapse-opener collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#features3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="features3">
                                    <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="features3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="features3" data-parent="#accordion1">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="features-detail">
                                        <div class="features-list">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Vendors Dashboard</h3>
                                                            <p>(Manage profile and password)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>List products</h3>
                                                            <p>(View list of products)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Add/ edit product page</h3>
                                                            <p>(without product variations)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Add/ edit product page</h3>
                                                            <p>(with product variations and attribute management)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Payment reports</h3>
                                                            <p>(With date filter)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Order history</h3>
                                                            <p>(View order history of products)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="features-item">
                                                        <div class="features-checkbox">
                                                            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" disabled>
                                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                            </label> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="features-content">
                                                            <h3>Order tracking</h3>
                                                            <p>(Track individual order via tracking number/ API)</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form-check-input").change(function() {
        var abc = []; //move the array to here
        $('li input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            var $row = $(this).closest('li');
            $('h3', $row).each(function(i) {
                abc.push($(this).text());
            })
            document.getElementById("features").value = abc.join(',');
        });
    });

 $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
                    var total = 0;
                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { // iterate through each checked element.
                        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
                    });
                    $("#total").val("$" + total.toFixed(2));

                });
</script>
```

now here I am getting values and showing them correctly in the input box of the form but if the user unchecks certain features they are not getting removed from the input field

basically I am storing values in the array "abc" on checkbox checked property but not able to remove on uncheck them.

Comment: Ah, your HTML code is incomplete .( missing the features input, the h3 whose 'text' you want to add as the selected value ) and also you have an unused method ( totalIt ) onClick aaaand also the checkbox is ' disabled ' by default. Please put in the effort and time to ask a correct question and edit your code . Else how do you expect we put the effort and time to help you ?

Comment: hi i just sent the code snippet.... totalit is used to calculate total amount...code is way too big and not possible to post here..

Comment: well then take the time and effort ( yes, i said that before ) to make a code snippet that reproduces your problem. How did the user who asnwered been able to remove the `totalIt`, to remove the `disabled` attribute, to add the `input ` with id `features` ? That's something you should've done. Because that's something related to the question, not the answer.

Comment: ok i will update as you say

Comment: i have updated code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move `document.getElementById("features").value = abc.join(',');` out of your `li .each()` function, then everything seems to work just fine.

Problem is that you are only updating the value of the input if there is a checked input.

**Demo**

```js
$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
  var abc = []; //move the array to here

  $('li input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('li');
    $('h3', $row).each(function(i) {
      abc.push($(this).text());
    })

  });
  document.getElementById("features").value = abc.join(',');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="features-item">
      <div class="features-checkbox">
        <label class="custom-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox"/>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="features-content">
        <h3>Order history</h3>
        <p>(View order history of products)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="features-item">
      <div class="features-checkbox">
        <label class="custom-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input ch2" name="product" value="0" type="checkbox"/>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="features-content">
        <h3>Order history2</h3>
        <p>(View order history of products)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<input id="features" />
```